# How to make XML sitemap to work after transfer from localhost?

Tags: xml-sitemap

My XML sitemap module was installed and enabled long time ago when I just started to make my website on WAMP/ localhost.....

Now the site is live and on real host and domain; but sitemap is still on:

`http://localhost/zen/sitemap.xml` with 1050 links....

```
Error loading stylesheet: An unknown error has occurred (805303f4)http://localhost/zen/sitemap.xsl
```

And I don't see any option to change it's path....

What should I do?

Can I somehow correct it's path or I have to reinstall?

If I reinstall, what happens with all settings?

Answer (score 1):

Did you define `base_url` in settings.php file? Try to set your current website address for `base_url`, then clear cache and run cron to generate sitemap. If this doesn't work, backup your database and run SQL query as:

```
UPDATE variable SET value='s:99:"http://example.com";' WHERE name='xmlsitemap_base_url';
```

Where the 99 is the length of your domain (including the http and all) and example.com is your domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the path here admin/config/search/xmlsitemap/settings -> Advanced settings

Answer (score 0):

In my experience you can simply solve that by running the cron once.

When doing that via Drush you need to append the `--uri` option. As during cron runs – which is when the sitemap gets regenerated – the `$base_url` is not available. Appending `--uri` makes the `$base_url` available again.

```
drush cron --uri=http://example.com
```

I guess when triggering the cron from the admin UI the `$base_url` gets retrieved from the form.